# Interface builder position off screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I have a container view showing a sidebar which is pinned to the main views leading edge. The sidebar is initial visible which is fine for iPads however I would like it to be hide initially for smaller devices. To do that I need to set the side bars trailing edge constraint to be (0 - its own width)

As far as I can see this is not possible in the interface builder. I have tried to do it in the viewDidLoad, checking if the device is an iPhone before doing self.sidebarX.constant = -self.sidebar.frame.width. This fails because viewDidLoad has not set up the views yet so the width is wrong. I also tried to do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews however the user sees the sidebar disappearing which isn't nice. I am sure there must be a common way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked it out. viewDidLayoutSubviews was the correct place to be doing this. At first when I tried it, it was showing the sidebar slide away as the view controller loaded. It turns out this is because I was calling my closeSidebar method which animates the side bar moving off screen. Changing this so it just sets the view off screen and adding a check to ensure this only done once on first load (as viewDidLayoutSubviews is called multiple times) does the job of hiding the the sidebar for certain devices without anyone seeing it happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this using xcode adaptative layout:

[image]

You can set the different position for all different screen types here, changing the constraints, positions, sizes to each different type you need.

You can install the layout of one object in different screen types using the dialog below:

[image]

Have a look in this 2 parts tutorial from raywenderlich [part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1) [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83130/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-2)

Comment: If you mean viewWillAppear then yes, but same issue :(

Comment: But how can I use that to set the initial leading edge constraint to be minus the sidebars width so it is initially off screen?

Comment: The changes you make in one type does not affect the other so you can just change and when you move from one to another they will have different values

Comment: But I mean, as far as I am aware there is now way to do the following. Using the compact width any heigh size class, set a constraint on the leading view to be negative the sidebars full width, meaning its hidden off screen when loaded on devices that match this size class.

Comment: Instead put it out screen just set it to hidden, but yes you should be able to set a negative constraint to one and a positive to another just be careful to use compact and regular, don't use any in this case

Comment: Instead put it out screen just set it to hidden -> I could do that but there are two problems 1) Im not sure its possible to hide a view for just one side class (I could be wrong though). 2) though I could hide the view in the code and then unhide it, but then I won't get the nice slide out motion. Also my main view is pinned to its trailing edge so while the side bar will be hidden, the main view will be pushed to the side as if it was there.

Comment: I add a tutorial that I think will help you figure out how to set the constraints for the two different sizes. I hope that helps you! :)